# Ctrl + Shift + ; in Google sheet gives me time 1 hour in the past

Tags: google-sheets, time

One can populate current time in Google spread sheet by hitting: Ctrl + Shift + ;.

However, since last 2-3 days, it shows time 1 hour in the past. How can I fix it?

p.s: Apparently someone think this shouldn't be on StackOverflow. Spreadsheet is not considered as a tool which programmers can use. Huh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

I have updated my answer since CodeCamper's answer was deleted.

> When you change the locale and time zone of a spreadsheet, it
> changes the spreadsheet's default date, time and even currency and
> number formatting. Ref: [Set a spreadsheet’s location & calculation settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cchange-locale-and-time-zone)
>
> On your computer, Open a spreadsheet in google sheets. Click File >
> Settings, Under "General", select "Locale" and "Time Zone" you want
> then Save.

In case, the time zone set is already correct, another thing that can affect the time is the Daylight savings time if you are in a country which adjusts their clock. By default, the Google Sheets time zone setting automatically applies the Daylight savings offset but, in your device's local time, you may have it turned off which causes them not to align by an hour.

[image]

[image]

Both the device and Sheets Time Zone are the same however the Daylight Savings is turned off on the desktop which causes the 1 hour difference.

**References:**

- [Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview)
- [Daylight Saving Time 2022: When Does the Time Change?](https://www.almanac.com/content/when-daylight-saving-time)

Comment: Thanks. I needed to just reset the time zone in spread sheet. I believe somehow changes in daylight savings caused it,